# use Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -Params

Tags: azure, powershell, cloud

I am trying to use the command like so:

```
a = 345
name = "myVM"
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $VMName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $FileName -Parameter @{"b" = "a"; "test" = "name"}
```

the script in the file isn't really important I am just trying to use params inside of it with values of params from the outside. If I put "b" = 345 it works but with the outside param (a), it doesn't so I wanted to know how to do it.
it does execute the script but ignores the commands using these params.

for reference the script is something like this:

```
New-Item -Path "." -Name "index.html" -ItemType "file" -Value $b
New-Item -Path "." -Name $test -ItemType "file" -Value "3333333"
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` to Invoke a run command on the VM. And the -Parameter is used to run the command parameter.

The the type for **-Parameter** is **Hashtable**, which maps keys to values. Any non-null object can be used as a key or as a value.

Invoke command is more like a batch script, so when we want to pass a pre-defined variable we have to use the **$** symbol without any double quotes (**""**). So you can solve your problem by following the code snippet below.

```sh
#Example
a = 345
name = "myVM"
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $VMName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $FileName -Parameter @{"b" = $a; "test" = $name}
```

Read this [Invoke-AzVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-6.6.0) document and [about_Hash_Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) document for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $VMName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $FileName -Parameter @{"b" = $a; "test" = $name}

It don't work. The same problem.
I have the script which create VM in azure:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Qwerty123456" -AsPlainText
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $password

$x = Get-Random 10000 -Minimum 10
$location = "East US"
$rgname = "testVM"+$x
$VMName = "vm1"

# Create Resource group 
New-AzResourceGroup -name $rgname -Location $location

# Create VM, vnet, publicIP, port 3389
New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgname `
   -Location $location `
   -Name "verdyshtest" `
   -VirtualNetworkName "virtnet" `
   -SubnetName 'verdyshnetwork' `
   -PublicIpAddressName "verdyshpublicIP" `
   -Image Win2019Datacenter `
   -OpenPorts 3389 `
   -Credential $cred

# Script only running after deploy
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMName $VMName -CommandId RunPowerShellScript -ScriptPath '.\2 Install app on VM.ps1'
```

In last count it can't to execute 'invoke-azvmruncommand', because of variable in parameters.
But in New-AzVM cmdlet variables works well.

Had a error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCBbm.png)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31650141)